# Prove that there is an n-ball B(a) in which f has the same sign as f(a)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a scalar field continuous at an interior point $a$ of a set $S$ in $\Bbb R^n$. If $f(a)$ is not equal to $0$, prove that there is an $n$-ball $B(a)$ in which $f$ has the same sign as $f(a)$.

*I think that this is another way of proving the definition of a limit in the context of scalar fields.

My attempt
Proof: Suppose $f(a)>0$, let $B[a]$ be the ball around $a$. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, for every ball $B[f(a)]$ there exist a ball $B[a]$ such that if $x$ is in $B[a]$ then $f$ is in $B[f(a)]$. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, $f$ is in $B[f(a)]$. Thus $f$ has the same sign as $f(a)$. QED

I'm doubtful about my proof as it doesn't look rigorous enough. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not good, you already started picking a ball $B[a]$. And what is the radius of all these balls? I'll do the case $f(a)>0$, you do $f(a)<0$ for practice (it is possible to do it at the same time, though). Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, given $\epsilon = f(a)/2 > 0$. By continuity, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in B(a,\delta) \implies \left|f(x)-f(a)\right| < f(a)/2$. So: $$-\frac{f(a)}{2} < f(x)-f(a) < \frac{f(a)}{2} \implies f(x) > \frac{f(a)}{2} > 0, \quad \forall\,x \in B(a,\delta).$$

Comment: Can't we pick a ball in the first place and then prove that f has the same sign as f(a)?

Comment: No, you have to prove that the ball *exists*, for starters

Comment: An extreme counter example: ${\rm id}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and $a = 1$. Then ${\rm id}(x)$ has the same sign as ${\rm id}(a)$ for all $x \in \left]-2,4\right[$ (I took radius $3$), and this is clearly wrong.